# looping through a dataframe to replace values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, replace

I'm trying to have terms in a dataframe, an old term (existing) and a new term that will replace it.
This dataframe is then used in the replace() process. Runnig the following presents a keyerror error `KeyError: "None of [Index([('HIS_COP_', ''), ('_Ply', ''), ('_Pt', '')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Manually this works:

```
    gdf['montype'].replace('HIS_COP_', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
    gdf['montype'].replace('_Ply', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
    gdf['montype'].replace('_Pt', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

code:

```
    montype = [['HIS_COP_', ''],
               ['_Ply', ''],
               ['_Pt','']]

    df = pd.DataFrame(montype, columns=['term_old', 'term_new'])

    for term in df:
        print(df)
        gdf[montype].replace(term['term_old'], term['term_new'], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary from nested list and pass to `replace`:

```
gdf['montype' ] = gdf['montype' ].replace(dict(montype), regex=True)
```

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529)

Comment: @Spatial Digger You are right, need `gdf['montype']`, answer was edited.